# Emitting `[MarshalAs(...)]` dynamically using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling, cil, reflection.emit

I need to create a dynamic .NET delegate with specially marshalled parameters (e.g. `[MarshalAs(UnamangedType.LPWStr)]`) at runtime using `System.Reflection.Emit`. This requires me to create a type inheriting `MulticastDelegate` (no problems so far), an appropriate constructor, and the `Invoke`-method with the specially marshalled parameters.

My C# code so far:

```
TypeBuilder type_builder = ...;

MethodBuilder method_builder = type_builder.DefineMethod(
    "Invoke",
    MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Public,
    CallingConventions.Standard,
    typeof(int),
    new[] { typeof(string) } // only an example - this array could hold any number of parameter types
);
ParameterBuilder parameter_1 = invoke.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.HasFieldMarshal, "arg0");

parameter_1.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(
    typeof(MarshalAsAttribute).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(UnmanagedType) }),
    new object[] { UnmanagedType.LPWStr }
));

// ...

type_builder.CreateType();
```

I can generate the dynamic assembly, however the application crashes upon invocation of the 'Invoke'-method due to invalid IL instructions.

After a closer inspection using the `peverify` and `ildasm`-tools I detect, that my code above emits the following IL:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance int32 Invoke (
        string arg0
    ) runtime managed
{
    .param [1]
    .custom instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute::.ctor(
            class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType) = (
        01 00 15 00 00 00 05 00 53 08 0c 41 72 72 61 79 /* ...huge binary blob... */ 00 00 00 00
    )

    // ...
}
```

Whereas the following should be the correct IL code:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance int32 Invoke (
        string marshal(lpwstr) arg0
    ) runtime managed
{
    // ...
}
```

*(Namely the `marshal(lpwstr)`-modifier on `arg0`!)*

### My Question

How do I have to change the code above to emit the correct marshalling information?

The MSDN documentation is not helping, as it always refers to the obsolete method [`MethodBuilder.SetMarshal(UnmanagedMarshal)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.setmarshal?view=netframework-4.8). Furthermore, the documentation only tells me to "emit the `MarshalAs` custom attribute instead" - which is pretty unhelpful, because this is exactly what I am doing.

*Note: I am using .NET Core 5*

### EDIT:

Creating the IL code for a delegate is not a problem. I've tested it and it works flawlessly. The only trouble I have is correctly implementing `marshal(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

This question is over two years old, but I **think** I may have found the issue here.

From what I can tell, `ParameterAttributes.HasFieldMarshal` is used to indicate that the default marshaling behavior will be used to marshal the *parameter*, which may have **fields** that require additional explicit marshaling, e.g. a `struct` which contains a field with the `MarshalAs` attribute:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string s; // field has explicit marshaling
}

public delegate void Foo(MyStruct s); // param uses default marshaling behavior
```

When you create the `ParameterBuilder` (with `DefineParameter`), you are establishing that the default marshaling behavior will be used for the parameter and its fields (respective to the `MarshalAs` attribute set on each field). Then, the call to `SetCustomAttribute` is ignored because the marshaling behavior for the parameter has already been defined.

The correct behavior (as you have described it) would be to pass `ParameterAttributes.None` when defining the parameter for which you will later call `SetCustomAttribute` to set the marshaling behavior.

(Incidentally, I ended up here because I was attempting the same thing, but passing the wrong parameter index due to a misreading of the `DefineParameter` documentation.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The project for which I initially asked this question has been set on hold due to the missing resolution to this problem. I will try your solution in the coming days/weeks and will comment my findings/results. However, I already want to thank you in advance for answering this question!

Comment: @unknown6656 my project [NativeGenericDelegates](https://github.com/monkey0506/native-generic-delegates) may be of interest to you, even if only for reference. I provide a full API that wraps runtime delegates with optional custom marshaling.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the repository you've linked. It sounds promising!